# How to fix performance issue while loading new animation in Lottie?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, lottie

I am trying to make a simple game with Xcode 11.2 which contains an animated loop background and a view which shows and changes various animations from several Lottie JSON files in project.

When I click the "Next" button to change the view animation, background view which is looping gets stuck for a second until the next animation inside the view is loaded an everything in the app freezes at the same time just like the background animation.

CPU usage varies from 30% to 63%.

I don't like to complicate the question, so I am just showing the way I used Lottie.

```
@IBAction func SubmitButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    showNextQuestion()
    
}

func showNextQuestion()->(){
    
    myTimer.invalidate()
    startCountdown(fromTime: 15)
    Manager.generateQuestion()
    lblLevel.text = String(Manager.questionNumber) + "/" + String(DataModel.Questions.count)
    nIndex = 0

    
    let animation = AnimationView(name: Manager.currentImage)
    
    animation.loopMode = .loop
    animation.play()
    animation.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
   animation.frame = self.AnimView.bounds
    animation.backgroundBehavior = .pauseAndRestore
    if AnimView.subviews.isEmpty{
        self.AnimView.addSubview(animation)
    }
    else {
        for one in imgImageView.subviews{
            one.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        self.AnimView.addSubview(animation)
    }
   
    AnswerCollectionView.reloadData()
    RandomCollectionView.reloadData()
    
}
```

I am interested in suggestions as to what the problem is related to - could it be related to a threading issue?

Comment: Run all UI updates on main thread DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: Rather than recreating the animation each time it plays how about creating it once and showing and hiding it by `isHidden` property.

Comment: its not a good idea when i use it in a quiz like app which consists of lot of lottie files in an array may be...i just want to be safe from every memory issues

Comment: i think @user3344236 is right

Comment: can someone explain how the exact code should look like

Answer (score 0):

In response to Jaseel.Dev, I created a function that returned a LottieView with the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                LottieView(name: animation)
            }
        }
```